# Computing scalar derivative by chain rule with matrix intermediary

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Consider a function function $h(x) = f(g(x))$ where $g(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $f(A): \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$.

How can I compute $\frac{d[h(x)]}{dx}$ in terms of the Jacobians of $g$ and $f$?

Comment: $h'(x)= Df_{g(x)}[g'(x)]$. Here, if $\gamma$ is a function from $\Bbb{R}\to V$ where $V$ is a normed vector space, then by $\gamma'(x)$ I mean the usual limit of the difference quotient $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\gamma(x+h)-\gamma(x)}{h}$. Here, $Df_A$ denotes the (Frechet) derivative of $f$ at the point $A$.

Comment: Hmmm. Would it not just be the multiplication of the Jacobians of $g$ and $f$ , one of which is $1\times(m*n)$ dimensional and the other that is $(m*n)\times$ 1 dimensional.

Comment: Yes, sure. The way I wrote my answer is in terms of linear transformations and vectors, which makes no reference to any basis. If you want, you can choose a basis, and do everything in terms of matrix representations. My only warning to you is that on the space $M_{m\times n}(\Bbb{R})$ of matrices, there is no "standard ordered basis", which means depending on conventions you can get different looking answers (hence when reading online, some places you'll see a transpose, sometimes you wont among other things).